# jQuery bind, unbind is not working

Tags: jquery, bind

I have written below code, but is not working as expected.

In Chrome, the **alert** is not working , ie. `alert('1');`

In Firefox or IE it is working fine,but if I comment out `alert('1')` it is not working,
This has already perplexed me for a long time.  I appreciate your help.

code:

```
$(function() {

    createDynamicTable();
    bindEvent();

    function bindEvent() {
        alert('1');
        $("td.editAble").unbind();
        $("td.editAble").bind("click", function(e) {
            $(this).unbind();
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  I just realized that could be a critical piece of missing information.

Comment: Do you have the HTML as well? Not all of it, but perhaps the part of the table with the td and editAble class name, which by the way is an odd spelling... camel case is for words, not syllables. Editable is one word....

Comment: I also see bindEvent() and bindEvent1(). Are those really different function names?  Where is the definition for bindEvent?  Can you make sure you're showing us the real, actual code?

Comment: I use jquery 1.7.2.  var tr = $("<tr>");
 var td = $("<td>");
 td = $("<td class=\"editAble\">");
 td.appendTo(tr);

Comment: Yeh, I got that. I'm asking you why you have bindEvent and bindEvent1.... if you're trying to call the bindEvent1 function, you have to also use that same name inside the document.ready.... this likely isn't working because the function definition name doesn't match the name of the function you're calling in ready, which is why I'm asking you if you're showing us all the code....

Comment: the function is bindEvent().i correct it

Comment: In short, it looks like you're using (the deprecated) unbind function correctly, it's just never being reached... In Chrome, use your debugger and step through the code. Put a breakpoint in and walk through to find out the execution steps. Good luck!

Comment: ok,i'll try,tks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery .bind/.unbind methods are deprecated as of release 3.0

The new jQuery methods for attaching/unattaching event handlers are .on/.off